# Excel 2003 Advanced Filer

Tags: excel, vba

I have These value also in the worksheet:

```
Cell location   Value
A1              Today()
B1              =TEXT(A1,"dddd")
G3              Day
H3              Day
I3              Day
G4              D
H5              =LEFT(B1,3)
I6              x
```

Now start from A3 to D19

```
Book Name   Code    QTY Day
.Net                    x
Book1       NBC     2   Mon
Book2       NAA     1   Wed
Book3       NBA     3   Tue/Mon
Oracle                  x
Book1       OB1     1   D
Book2       OXZ     1   Fri
Book3       OPS     2   Sun
Book4       OPR     1   Thu
Java                    x
Book1       JPS     1   D
Book2       JJJ     4   Sat
PHP                     x
Book1       PMW     3   Wed/Tue
Book2       PHY     2   D
Book3       PED     1   Fri
```

Today is Thursday and when I open the workbook its view should be like this:

```
Book Name   Code    QTY Day
Oracle
Book1       OB1     1   D
Book4       OPR     1   Thu
Java
Book1       JPS     1   D
PHP
Book2       PYH     2   D
```

I have mention x as day for category of the books because I want category name row in the
view also.

Means all rows who have D (Daily) in day column and first three char in the day
column whether they are Thu or /Thu (for Thursday example).

I have done it by VBA :

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
        Range("A3:D19").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
        Range("G3:I6"), Unique:=False
End Sub
```

But it is giving me below view:

```
Book Name   Code    QTY Day
.Net                    x   <---Not required
Oracle                  x   
Book1       OB1     1   D
Book4       OPR     1   Thu
Java                    x
Book1       JPS     1   D
PHP                     x   
Book2       PHY     2   D
```

I don't want above mentioned rows because there are no books for today or nor they are 
in daily view.

Kindly let me know, I am clear in my question or provide more details please.

Comment: Looks like it's working exactly like it should? It's filtering on "D", "Thu", and "x", as those are the values in your G3:I6 Range. .Net has "x" in your sample data so it will appear just like all the other books with "x"

Comment: Yes, it right but since on Thursday there are no book in .Net category, so I just do not want to have this row in the filtered view please.

Comment: I think you need to provide more information. Like i said, i believe your code is working as expected. Your criteria range is G3:I6 which contains "D", the first three letters of todday, and "x". .Net has the value "x" in the Day column so it will appear in your filtered results. Do you not want the x's to appear?

Comment: Actually I have just shown how I am trying to achieve the required output which is not giving me.  I want to have only those rows who have 'D', first 3 characters of the system day and 'x' in the day column.  Now, with 'x' marked rows should only appear when in the subsequent rows have 'D' or first three characters.  In the above example data, there are no books which have neither 'D' nor 'Thu' in the day columns, so I also want that .Net 'x' marked rows should also not be in the output.  Kindly let me, if I need to explain more.

Comment: i.e. output should be something like this select * from data where day in ('D',first three characters of the system day, having count(*) > 0) because if there are no rows for the said category i.e. (.Net, Oracle, Java, PHP) those rows should also be not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my assumptions are correct, you are using the x to indicate the row is the book type. Given this data structure, after you filter the data, you'll need to check if subsequent rows have an x in the day column. If they do, then you there were no books between those two rows, and therefore no books for that book type. To do this, you'll need to use the `SpecialCells` function and keep track of the row numbers as you loop through the rows of visible cells. Your fully updated code should be the following:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim myRange As Range
Dim curRowWithX As Integer
Dim lastRowWithX As Integer

    Range("A3:D19").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
    Range("G3:I6"), Unique:=False

    ' Get all visible cells in the filtered area
    Set myRange = Range("A3:D19").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    ' initialize row indexes
    curRowWithX = 0
    lastRowWithX = 0

    For Each Row In myRange.Rows
        ' Check if Day value of current row is x
        If Row.Cells(1, 4) = "x" Then

            ' Store current row and check if last Day value was x
            ' in the visible range was x, and hide if so
            curRowWithX = Row.Row
            If lastRowWithX > 0 Then Rows(lastRowWithX).EntireRow.Hidden = True

        Else
            ' Reset the current row index
            curRowWithX = 0
        End If

        ' Update the last row index with the current indext
        lastRowWithX = curRowWithX

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Great! If this answer works for you, feel free to "accept" the answer by clicking the check next to the answer